# Why my splash:select always fail in this simple code (Splash)?

Tags: web-scraping, select, lua, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I want to select the "2nd-page" button at the end of [this website](https://www.livecoinwatch.com/) using Splash code (Docker/Browser ver).
I even used the "copy Selector" function of Chrome to get to the extract part, I also checked with F12 and CtrlF and found the extract position. But somehow my code still fail at the `select` function

Below is my simple Lua Splash code:

```
function main(splash, args)

  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  url = args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  next_page = assert(splash:select('div > div.py20 > div > nav > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a'))
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  next_page:mouse_click()
  return {splash:html()}
 end
```

My code always fails at the `next_page` line with an assertion error:

```
{
    "error": 400,
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "info": {
        "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]",
        "line_number": 8,
        "error": "assertion failed!",
        "type": "LUA_ERROR",
        "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:8: assertion failed!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn scrapy/splash, or are you actually trying to get some information from that page?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I'm learning a Splash/Scrap course from Udemy and they use this website. Still, they only show how to scrap data from page 1. I'm trying to figure out how to get the rest

Comment: Sorry but splash:select only works with CSS